# MATLAB: Average data from non-uniform to uniform grid

Tags: matlab, moving-average, binning

I have data taken at 10 minute intervals, but with a lot of data gaps, and I want to average it onto a uniform hourly time grid. I'm looking for an efficient way to take the 3 potential points on either side of each hour and average them onto the hour.

Example:

t_old = [1:35 1:45 1:55 -- 2:15 2:25] %here -- is missing data

t_new = 2:00

data_old = [1 2 3 -- 5 6]

data_new = 3.4

Problem is that there are enough data gaps, I can't just straight bin average. I know I could do it by going to each new time step and using find() with that half hour offset, but I feel like that would be horribly inefficient and slow. Any ideas on a quicker way to do this? Perhaps some way to bin to the nearest hour and then average bins?

Edit for MWE:

```
t=1:10; 
tnew=2:2:8;
data=1:10; 
t(3)=[];
data(3)=[];
dt=2; 
for i=1:length(tnew)
    datanew(i)=mean(data(find(t>(tnew(i)-dt) & t<(tnew(i)+dt)))); 
end

datanew
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But from what you show here, wouldn't linear interpolation (e.g. [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)) do the trick?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I translated his time strings into numeric values, then used `interp1(t_old,data_old,data_new)`
and it gives 3.5 as a result.

Comment: Is there a way to get interp1 to use an average of the nearest 6 neighbors, but only if they exist within half an hour of the point? I get that it can use weighted nearest neighbor, or linear/spline interpolation, but I just want a simple average. I'm updating the MWE now.

Comment: @vityav, I tried a way of grouping your data into constant time interval bins using `histc` then doing the mean on each bin, but the method run at roughly the same speed than your own example method (and also your method use an overlap of time for each mean, while this doesn't so the results are slightly different). On the other hand, for your code, you can shave a few % of execution time by pre-allocating your datanew `datanew=zeros(tnew);`, and by using logical indexing inside the loop: `datanew(i) = mean(data((t>(tnew(i)-dt) & t<(tnew(i)+dt))))` (basically just remove the `find`).

Comment: @Hoki, what was your histc approach? The averages shouldn't overlap, I just made a poor example. The other two tips are very helpful, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

```
tnew_lb = tnew-dt; %// lower bound
tnew_ub = tnew+dt; %// upper bound
[r,c] = find(bsxfun(@gt,t',tnew_lb) & bsxfun(@lt,t',tnew_ub));
datanew = accumarray(c,data(r),[], @mean)
```

---

**Approach #2**

```
timestep = min(diff(t)); %// Minimum time-stepsize for t
t_all = min(t):timestep:max(t); %// create all the timesteps
[b1,b2] = ismember(t,t_all);

ind = bsxfun(@plus,[tnew(1)-dt+1:tnew(1)+dt-1]',[0:numel(tnew)-1]*dt);
[v1,v2] = ismember(ind,t_all(b2));
vind = v2~=0;
v2(v2==0) = NaN;
v2(vind) = data(v2(vind));
out = nanmean(v2);
```

Comment: This is a little faster for 100k clean, regular points (23s to my 25s), but on my actual data (with gaps and NaNs), my code works in 30 seconds with 200MB memory, and this somehow takes up 12GB of memory and brings the system to a halt for a few minutes before I can kill it.

Comment: @vityav Damn! That must be `bsxfun` then!

Comment: Yeah, that generates a 6.7GB 100k by 100k matrix for each call. I like the idea for smaller problems, though.

Comment: With the missing data, that fifth line containing "t_all(b2)" doesn't work, since a lot of the b2 values are 0, and it won't index a 0. If I can get data onto the t_all grid, though, I have a function that does block averaging. Problem is, where you do the first ismember, I get a lot of round-off errors in my time values so most of the time steps aren't detected as being identical.

Comment: @vityav Let me ask you, are you using floating point timesteps. I think for `ismember` to work, it needs to avoid the dreadful floating point precision issues and for that one remedy is to scale every element of `t` such that the resultant `t` has all integer values.

Comment: @vityav After calculating `t_all`, interpolate `t` with `t = interp1(t_all, t_all, t, 'nearest')` and then use `[b1,b2] = ismember(t,t_all);` and keep rest of the code the same. Check if there's any b2 is zero (there must not be) and run the code and let me know?

Comment: this is very close. It gives me the indices of existing time steps around the desired timesteps. However, `v2` refers to indices in `t_all`, which has far more indices than `data`. How can I map those values back to `t`?

Answer (score 1):

After your comment asking about the `histc` approach, I post it here. Although this is **not** the fastest method if that's all you want to do with your data, it may be useful in case you need to reuse the bin information (classification of data) later on.

The following code:

```
%% // prepare
clear all
t=1:10; 
tnew=2:2:8;
data=1:10; 
t(3)=[];
data(3)=[];
nLoop = 50000 ;

%% // initial method
tic ;
for iLoop = 1:nLoop
    clear datanew
    dt=1; 
    for i=1:length(tnew)
        datanew(i)=mean( data( find(t>=(tnew(i)-dt) & t<(tnew(i)+dt)) )); 
    end
end
toc

%% // initial method optimized
tic ;
for iLoop = 1:nLoop
    clear datanew
    dt=1; 
    datanew = zeros( size(tnew) ) ;
    for i=1:length(tnew)
        datanew(i)=mean( data( t>=(tnew(i)-dt) & t<(tnew(i)+dt) )); 
    end

end
toc

%% // histc method
xedges = [tnew(1)-dt tnew+dt] ; %// => xedges = [1:2:9] ;
tic
for iLoop = 1:nLoop
    clear newdata
    newdata = zeros( size(tnew)) ;
    [n,bins] = histc( data , xedges ) ;
    for iBin=1:length(n)-1
        newdata(iBin) = mean( data(bins==iBin) ); 
    end
end
toc
```

produces the following output:

```
Elapsed time is 3.177801 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.910844 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.948526 seconds.
```

I ran it multiple times with different loop iteration number, the results were always consistent. The *optimized* initial method is always faster than the *histc* method. I am not a big fan of the histc method because after we already binned all the data, it still involves a loop and a comparison (`data(bins==iBin)`) instead of direct indexing.

The comparisons are slightly different though. One is of type `>` and operates on floating point numbers, while the other one is `=` and compares indexes (so theoretically integers but I am not sure how Matlab represent them internally so it may not be a benefit).

Anyway, this could result in different execution time than I obtained with bigger and more complex data sets, so you are welcome to try theses methods on your real data and feel free to let us know how it works for you.

---

ps: I modified slightly your initial example so there is no more overlap in the averaged time windows (changed `dt=1` and one `>` to `>=`). This way all methods return the same results.